# updateTrackingAreas: override only works for the first 2 times?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift, cocoa

On **El Capitan** in **Xcode 7 beta** using **Swift 2.0**, I subclassed a `NSView` to use as a prototype view of `NSCollectionView`'s item view, and override the `updateTrackingAreas:` method to do the mouse tracking. The `NSCollectionView` was inside a `NSPopover`.

It seems that only the first 2 times the `updateTrackingAreas:` will be called, as the debug log shows. The code was like the following:

```
override func updateTrackingAreas() {

    Swift.print("updateTrackingAreas:")

    if trackingArea != nil {
        self.removeTrackingArea(trackingArea!)
    }

    trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(
        rect: self.bounds,
        options: [NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited, NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways],
        owner: self,
        userInfo: nil
    )

    if trackingArea != nil {
        self.addTrackingArea(trackingArea!)
    }

    var mouseLocation = self.window?.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream

    mouseLocation = self.convertPoint(mouseLocation!, fromView: nil)

    if CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, mouseLocation!) {
        mouseEntered(NSEvent())
    } else {
        mouseExited(NSEvent())
    }

    super.updateTrackingAreas()
}
```

The first 2 times when the popover was opened, I can see the console log shows `updateTrackingAreas:`. Then the tracking failed and no logs either.

**EDIT:**

When I commented out this part like:

```
//var mouseLocation = self.window?.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream

mouseLocation = self.convertPoint(mouseLocation!, fromView: nil)

if CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, mouseLocation!) {
    mouseEntered(NSEvent())
} else {
    mouseExited(NSEvent())
}
```

The problem will no longer exists.

And the following code makes no differences:

```
if let window = self.window {
    var mouseLocation = window.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream
    mouseLocation = self.convertPoint(mouseLocation, fromView: nil)
    if let event = NSApplication.sharedApplication().currentEvent {
        if NSPointInRect(mouseLocation, self.bounds) {
            mouseEntered(event)
        } else {
            mouseExited(event)
       }
   }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, I just reinstall OS X Yosemite and compiled it again with Xcode 7 beta 1. The problem no longer exists. Might just be a bug of El Capitan. I'll report it to Apple. Thank you all.

Comment: Why do you need to do the hit-testing in this method? Why can't you just handle the ``mouseEntered`` and ``mouseExited`` events in the usual way?

Comment: Because when you scroll on the view, `mouseEntered:` and `mouseExited:` will be ignored. The question is not regarding the reason why I did it, but rather why it did not work on the 3rd time on.

Comment: The reasons why you did it are important since your code isn't working the way you expected. The answer to your question may be that your question was the wrong line of thinking anyway (ie, your approach and/or assumptions may be flawed). Instead of being defensive - or worse, stubborn - about the exact kind of answer you want, treat us with the kind of mutual respect you expect for yourself and answer our own requests for clarification.

Comment: Sorry it just read it that way. English is not my native language and I can't be sure if I'm accidentally pissed anyone off. But most of the cases I saw people question about the intention rather than thinking into the problem. Even if the intention of this question is wrong, still doesn't change the fact that the question itself is valid. If the code is correct, there should be no reason it didn't work on the 3rd time. (It worked exactly twice, that does not read coincidence to me.) Maybe I just wanted to know, not to archive anything. So, why not? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just reinstall OS X **Yosemite** and compiled it again with **Xcode 7** beta 1. *The problem no longer exists.*

Might just be a bug of El Capitan. Already reported it to Apple.

Thank you all.

Comment: This isn’t an answer, as it doesn’t show any understanding of the problem and is useless to any reader but you. Please don’t make this the accepted answer.

Comment: Chill. It's a bug, from an outdated _beta_ version of Xcode and Swift from _6_ years ago. I don't see why this isn't the answer as it solved the problem as it's did solved my problem, by Apple itself, and can no longer be produced, which fits the definition of marking as an answer. Leaving it unsolved would be wasting people's time trying to figure out a problem that caused by a reported bug. If you feel like it, please by all means do a full reverse engineering of Xcode 7 beta 1 SDK and post a new answer regarding why this happened. I'll mark that as the answer if it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a newly-created event instance to `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()`. I realize that this is because you can't pass nil in the Swift variant of the method but perhaps you should pass the current event instead (`NSApplication` and `NSWindow` both have a `currentEvent()` method). Have you tried this?

Comment: I updated the code in my question post. The first `updateTrackingAreas:` did not even print on the 3rd time. But thanks for the info. :)

Comment: I believe I said just that: "I realize that this is because you can't pass nil..."  Please reread my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the `mouseLocation` in updateTrackingAreas is senseless.

From the docs of [updateTrackingAreas](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/updateTrackingAreas):

> Invoked automatically when the view’s geometry changes such that its tracking areas need to be recalculated.

This is usually due to frame change. It will be called as many times as you view changes it's frame or position. I doubt you've implemented live-resizing/moving feature on your view, this is the only way mouse inside view's frame can be the source of your view's geometry change.

Comment: The view shows up in the same location every time, and it's fixed sized. Also, it doesn't explain why it always not work on the 3rd time. And since `updateTrackingAreas:` was overridden and invoked super.updateTrackingAreas(), it shouldn't be affecting the outcome without any error log or sort?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the geometry may change while setting a view as a subview too. If you instantiate the popover only once, there must be some cached view. Does the mouse-tracking stops working at 3rd time?

Comment: yes, every 3rd time. Is there a way to prevent cache? Like a force `needDisplay = true` to make sure it's the cause? And if so, is there an alternative way to do the tracking when scroll?

Comment: Not sure this is a cache, just guessed. Try calling a super, then your code. If that doesn't help, try to reload collection view to drop cached views. If that doesn't help either, show some sample project here so we could help to locate a trouble.

Comment: call super before the altering makes no sense, it will just be nothing was changed as `trackingArea` was the same when it's updated, the changes were made after the super update the view. But I did try it anyways, just for sure. The problem still exists.

Comment: if a collection view reloading doesn't help too - provide some sample project. Maybe you'vу just missed something important.